# Round up or down an entire column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
        A
0  31.353
1  28.945
2  17.377
```

I want to create a new df["B"] with A column values round up to 5.
The desired output:

```
        A      B
0  31.353   35.0
1  28.945   30.0
2  17.377   20.0
```

I´ve tried:

```
def roundup5(x):
    return int(math.ceil(x / 5.0)) * 5
df["B"] = df["A"].apply(roundup5)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'
```

Comment: Did you try `float(x)/5.0` in your `roundup5()` function?

Comment: Could there be any empty values in column A? Or anything that is assigned as str type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need convert values to `float`s first, then divide and use [`numpy.ceil`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html) with multiple:

```
df["B"] = df["A"].astype(float).div(5.0).apply(np.ceil).mul(5)
```

---

```
df["B"] = np.ceil(df["A"].astype(float).div(5.0)).mul(5)
```

---

Loop version:

```
def roundup5(x):
    return int(math.ceil(float(x) / 5.0)) * 5.0
df["B"] = df["A"].apply(roundup5)
```

---

```
print (df)
        A     B
0  31.353  35.0
1  28.945  30.0
2  17.377  20.0
```

**Timings**:

```
[30000 rows x 1 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [327]: %timeit df["B1"] = df["A"].apply(roundup5)
35.7 ms ± 4.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [328]: %timeit df["B2"] = df["A"].astype(float).div(5.0).apply(np.ceil).mul(5)
1.25 ms ± 76.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [329]: %timeit df["B3"] = np.ceil(df["A"].astype(float).div(5.0)).mul(5)
1.19 ms ± 22.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```